# brew install mysql, error when trying to stop the server

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

After:

```
brew install mysql
mysql_install_db
```

and I try to `stop` the MySQL server:

```
$ mysql.server stop
Shutting down MySQL
.. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

How can I fix the above error? Thanks!

Info:

```
$ mysql -v
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.1.51 Source distribution
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The install instructions for mysql suggest copying `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.1.54/com.mysql.mysqld.plist` to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` so that Mac OS X will automatically launch mysqld when you login.

If you've set up mysqld this way then the `launchd` process, which controls LaunchAgents in Mac OS X v10.4 and above, will automatically restart the mysqld process as soon as it is being killed by the `mysql.server stop` command. This might be the reason for the error message, because the server is being automatically restarted.

Just tested this on my Mac. Ran the `mysql.server stop` command ten times and each time 'launchd' restarted the msyqld process after about a second. Six times the command ended with a "SUCCESS!" message. Four times it ended with the "ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file" message.

UPDATE: Just realised I didn't mention how to stop the mysqld server if it is being started by launchd.

Here is the command to stop the mysqld daemon.

`launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist`

Comment: The file is now `homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried running `killall mysqld`?

Comment: Solved all my problems. I installed mysql first by dmg. then by brew.:D

Comment: This didn't work for me - launchctl would instantly restart mysql

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try..

1. Navigate to the problem's parent directory `cd YOURPATH/usr/local/mysql`
2. `rm -rf *.local.err` (deletes file)
3. `touch YOURUSERNAME.local.pid` (generates new *.local.pid file the error thrown was complaining about)
4. cd back into your project and restart mysql using `mysql.server start`