# MySQL error on server stop

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [brew install mysql, error when trying to stop the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066618/brew-install-mysql-error-when-trying-to-stop-the-server)

I installed MySQL with Homebrew. The server is running but when i stop it mysql.server stop I get the following error:

Shutting down MySQL
..... ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Are you running a linux server?

Comment: Homebrew is a package manager for Mac OS X. http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,240976,242485#msg-242485 you have something very simmilar (I says `It was due to some unsupported parameters in /etc/my.cnf (taken over from 5.0...)`)